# How do you loop to get accuracy scores of various logistic regression test sizes in Python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am trying to loop the different test sizes to understand the optimum test size for the highest correct prediction accuracy for logistic regression.

Basically, in the below code, I am trying to loop through the "ts" in the defined range (ts_range).
And I get *" TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer "*

Anyone has a solution to fix this error or anyone knows a different neat approach to print the accuracy scores of different test sizes of logistic regression?

Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
ts_range = range(0,0.6)
ts_scores = []
for ts in ts_range:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = ts, random_state=4)
    y_pred = logisticreg.predict(X_test)
    scores = (metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    ts_scores.append(scores.mean())

print(ts_scores)
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` is used to create integer sequences: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` for example.

If you want to create this sequence: `0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6` for example you could do:

```
ts_range = [n/10 for n in range(7)]
```

Comment: that gives another error " ValueError: test_size=0.0 should be either positive and smaller than the number of  a float in the (0, 1) range"

Comment: @Adam seems like 0 is an illegal value.